# Comparing rows in a text file

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I have a file like this separated by tab:

```
1 abc
2 abc
3 def
4 abc
1 abc
5 def
```

I want to generate another file by comparing the consecutive rows of the second column. The deisred output is like this:

```
1 2
1 4
3 5
```

I tried this way but no luck:

```
awk '{
dat[$2]++;
}
END{
for (var in dat)
if (var==$2){print $1,previous};
previous =$1}' file.txt
```

Any suggestion to achieve this using awk

Comment: Explain logic as well, clearly

Comment: It is unclear how your output relates to the input...

Comment: If you are trying to record the values of col 1 where col 2 is the same, you can do `awk '{dat[$2]=dat[$2] FS $1} END{ for (k in dat) print k, dat[k]}'` and then process that string of entries as you need...

Comment: 3 and 5 are not consecutive!

Comment: your explaination and the sample are not corresponding. Give a bit more info on output building, whiy no 1 6 after 1 4 ( or 1 1 if info is not line nr but first field) and why 3 5 and not 3 6 in this case

Answer (score 1):

this does compare all not just consecutive, only prints when there are matches, so will ignore unique entries

```
$ awk '{if($2 in a) print $1,a[$2]; else a[$2]=$1}' file

2 1
4 1
1 1
5 3
```

note that `1 1` entry appears since you have `1 abc` it twice in the input file.

to swap the columns change to `print a[$2],$1` in the if statement.  To eliminate self references for duplicate entries you can add another condition `if($2!=a[$1])` before print etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot faster if you sort your input file:

```
$ sort -k 2d data| awk '{ if (last==$2 && $1 != firstnum) { printf("%d\t%d\n", firstnum, $1); }; if (last!=$2) { last=$2; firstnum=$1; printf("%d\t%d\n", firstnum, firstnum); }}'
1   1
1   2
1   4
3   3
3   5
```

I'm not sure if you want to print the (1,1) and (3,3) pairs or not. But I figure if you have a key that only appears on one line, you might want to print that, so I left it in. You can take out the second printf if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '   {
        if ( ! ( $2 in Ps ) ) Os[++Oi] = $2
        # Line nr reference
        Ps[$2] = Ps[$2] " " NR
        # first field reference
        Ps[$2] = Ps[$2] " " $1
        }
     END {
        for ( i=1; i <= Oi; i++ ) {
           Size = split( Ps[ Os[ i]], aPls)
           for ( j = 2; j <= Size; j++) {
              printf( "%s\t%d\n", aPls[1], aPls[ j])
              }
           }
        }
     ' YourFile
```

- you need to remember at first read 1) the place of the first occurence of field 2 and also reference to other lines with same pattern
- i choose to put it in 2 array for reading the file only once but you could reread the same file and print at this second run
- the arrays

  - Ps contains the place of all occurence of a pattern (index is the pattern)
  - Os contains the list of first occurence, index is sequential, ordered